# Ayuda con un JFrame para que abra otro

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo un `JFrame` para un proyecto, se me ha pedido que pase la ventana que tenia a ser una ventana secundaria, es decir, que se abra desde otra ventana que seria la principal.

Aqui esta el codigo de la ventana secundaria(La que deberia poder abrir desde la principal). Esta en el mismo proyecto y el mismo paquete.

```
package neuronaia;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Aprendizaje extends JFrame {

JFrame Ap = new JFrame();
Ap.setLayout(null);
Ap.setSize(350,350);            
Ap.setTitle("Aprendizaje");
Ap.setDefaultCloseOperation(Ap.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Ap.setVisible(true);
Ap.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

//Instanciando Cuadros de Texto         
JLabel lx1 = new JLabel("X1");
Ap.add(lx1);
lx1.setBounds(25, 15, 25, 20);

JTextField textx1 = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx1);
textx1.setBounds(25, 35, 35, 30);

JLabel lx2 = new JLabel("X2");
Ap.add(lx2);
lx2.setBounds(125, 15, 25, 20);

JTextField textx2 = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx2);
textx2.setBounds(125, 35, 35, 30);

JLabel ly1 = new JLabel("Y1");
Ap.add(ly1);
ly1.setBounds(250, 10, 25, 30);

JTextField texty1 = new JTextField();
Ap.add(texty1);
texty1.setBounds(250, 35, 35, 30);

JTextField textx1a = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx1a);
textx1a.setBounds(25, 90, 35, 30);

JTextField textx2a = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx2a);
textx2a.setBounds(125, 90, 35, 30);

JTextField texty1a = new JTextField();
Ap.add(texty1a);
texty1a.setBounds(250, 90, 35, 30);

JTextField textx1b = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx1b);
textx1b.setBounds(25, 145, 35, 30);

JTextField textx2b = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx2b);
textx2b.setBounds(125, 145, 35, 30);

JTextField texty1b = new JTextField();
Ap.add(texty1b);
texty1b.setBounds(250, 145, 35, 30);

JTextField textx1c = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx1c);
textx1c.setBounds(25, 195, 35, 30);

JTextField textx2c = new JTextField();
Ap.add(textx2c);
textx2c.setBounds(125, 195, 35, 30);

JTextField texty1c = new JTextField();
Ap.add(texty1c);
texty1c.setBounds(250, 195, 35, 30);
//Fin cuadros de texto

//Botones
JButton button1 = new JButton("Aceptar");
Ap.add(button1);
button1.setBounds(75, 300, 100, 20);
```

Este es el codigo de mi ventana principal. Quiero un boton que me abra la ventana de la Clase Aprendizaje.

```
package neuronaia;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    JFrame Mw = new JFrame();
    Mw.setLayout(null);
    Mw.setSize(350,350);            
    Mw.setDefaultCloseOperation(Mw.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Mw.setVisible(true);
    Mw.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JButton Apr = new JButton("Aprendizaje");
    Mw.add(Apr);
    Apr.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 30);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder abrir un `JFrame` el código que tiene en la clase aprendizaje, debería ir en el constructor de dicha clase, además si la clase extiende de `JFrame` , no es necesario crear una nueva instancia  solo sería necesario reemplazar  `Ap` por `this`.

Además declarar las variables de los controles a nivel de clase para emplearlas en algún otro proceso dentro del `JFrame` *posteriormente*

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Aprendizaje  extends JFrame {
    private JLabel lx1,lx2,ly1;
    private JTextField  textx1,textx2,texty1,
                        textx1a,textx2a,texty1a,
                        textx1b,textx2b,texty1b,
                        textx1c,textx2c,texty1c;
    private JButton button1;
    public Aprendizaje(){
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(350,350);            
    this.setTitle("thisrendizaje");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //Instanciando Cuadros de Texto         
    lx1 = new JLabel("X1");
    this.add(lx1);
    lx1.setBounds(25, 15, 25, 20);
    textx1 = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1);
    textx1.setBounds(25, 35, 35, 30);
    lx2 = new JLabel("X2");
    this.add(lx2);
    lx2.setBounds(125, 15, 25, 20);
    textx2 = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2);
    textx2.setBounds(125, 35, 35, 30);
    ly1 = new JLabel("Y1");
    this.add(ly1);
    ly1.setBounds(250, 10, 25, 30);
    texty1 = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1);
    texty1.setBounds(250, 35, 35, 30);
    textx1a = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1a);
    textx1a.setBounds(25, 90, 35, 30);
    textx2a = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2a);
    textx2a.setBounds(125, 90, 35, 30);
    texty1a = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1a);
    texty1a.setBounds(250, 90, 35, 30);
    textx1b = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1b);
    textx1b.setBounds(25, 145, 35, 30);
    textx2b = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2b);
    textx2b.setBounds(125, 145, 35, 30);
    texty1b = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1b);
    texty1b.setBounds(250, 145, 35, 30);
    textx1c = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1c);
    textx1c.setBounds(25, 195, 35, 30);
    textx2c = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2c);
    textx2c.setBounds(125, 195, 35, 30);
    texty1c = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1c);
    texty1c.setBounds(250, 195, 35, 30);
    //Fin cuadros de texto
    //Botones
     button1 = new JButton("Aceptar");
    this.add(button1);
    button1.setBounds(75, 300, 100, 20);
  }
}
```

En su clase `MainWindow` le haría falta solo el `listener` al botón y llamar  a la Aprendizaje

```
JButton Apr = new JButton("Aprendizaje");
Apr.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
 {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      Aprendizaje ap = new Aprendizaje();
   }
});
```